# Encrypted data at rest when decrypted

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption

I was reading about encryption and had a question about it in general.
If I have a laptop with an encrypted SSD which I decrypt on boot up, it means it is all in plain text/data right?

If I do a hard shutdown or snatch that laptop while running, it means that the confidentiality of my data on that disk isn't ensured? If so, are there any safeguards on how to prevent attackers from reading the data?

That means encrypted data at rest should only be decrypted when needed.
Am I correct in this thought?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way hard disk encryption usually works is that the data stored on the disk is always encrypted.  When you boot the system, the decryption key is loaded into memory by the kernel and when data is read off the disk, it is decrypted.  As data is written back to the disk, it is encrypted first.  Therefore, there is usually never any data on the disk that's unencrypted (unless you have an unencrypted partition), so a hard shutdown is not a problem for security.

However, if the machine is powered on and booted, then the key is in memory, and data can be decrypted.  This is usually true even if the system is suspended (but not hibernated).  As mentioned by multithr3at3d, this data can often be recovered from memory for a few minutes after the machine is powered off.  Beyond that, the key is usually not recoverable, and the data is safe.

If you know you are about to go into a risky situation, such as when passing through customs, you may wish to power off your machine reasonably well in advance to protect its data.  If you do an urgent forced shutdown, your data will probably be unrecoverable unless someone can open the laptop and extract the key relatively quickly; it's far better to do that than do nothing.  Similarly, if you're concerned about a snatch-and-grab, power off (or on Linux, hibernate) your machine before traveling with it.

If you have especially sensitive data that you do not normally want to be decrypted when using your laptop, then put that data on a separately encrypted partition and decrypt it only when you need to.  This makes it much more likely that if a rogue process or human intervention compromises the system that your data won't be accessible.  Most people using an encrypted disk are willing to accept the fact that all data can be decrypted when the machine is on and so don't feel the need to do this, but your circumstances or level of comfort may dictate otherwise.

Comment: For the first paragraph. Is there a case the full disk encryption does not work in the usual way?

Comment: I cannot say that nobody has done something different, since I only know how a few of the most common packages work.  But I'm not aware of anyone doing it differently.

Answer (score 1):

Your SSD is likely much larger than your RAM. In order for the entire drive to be decrypted, it would need to fit in RAM. This is not feasible, so this doesn't happen. Data is decrypted and moved to RAM as it is needed (or cached). If you do a hard shutdown, any decrypted data in RAM will be discarded (with note to the last paragraph below).

But this doesn't matter too much if the computer is taken while powered on. In reality, the threat is that your decryption key will be accessible in RAM, and once retrieved, can decrypt the rest of the disk.

As mentioned earlier, data only remains in RAM while it is powered, and will decay once power is removed. However, RAM does not immediately become cleared; depending on circumstances, it can be possible for recoverable data to remain in RAM for seconds to even minutues, especially if the RAM can be cooled quickly (e.g. liquid nitrogen or other methods). This may allow for a [cold boot attack](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_boot_attack), or the RAM could be removed and read by a specialized system.

Comment: Wikipedia gives reference to 90 minutes to this https://www.researchgate.net/publication/326211565_Cold_Boot_Attack_On_Cell_Phones_Cryptographic_Attacks Very reliable source.

Comment: Thanks for the paper! It gave me a great insight into it.